# Update a value using MySQL Events

Tags: mysql, events, datetime

I would like to create an event in MySQL in order to change a value in a table. The event checks whether a date (particularly, the TIME() part of a TIMESTAMP field) is more than the current date. Obviously, I have a `time_stamp` and an `active` column in a table named 'active'. This is what I have

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
DO
SELECT @time:= time_stamp FROM active WHERE user_id = 1;
SELECT @time2:= TIMESTAMP(@time);
SELECT @active:=TIMEDIFF(@time2,DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -15 SECOND));
UPDATE active SET active=if(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(@active))>=0,1,0) WHERE user_id=1;
```

As far as I have seen, the SELECT part with the variables works fine, that is, TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(@active)) looks like a regressive count starting with 15 (provided I updated the 'time_stamp' field properly).

The intended behavior is that when TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(@active)) reach 0, the UPDATE query would change the value of the 'active' field from 1 to 0 (the default value is 1). However, it doesn't do anything.

**UPDATE**: To be precise, sometimes it changes the value to 0 but when TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(@active)) is still positive.

**SECOND UPDATE**: I recently tried this one:

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
DO
SELECT @time:= time_stamp FROM active WHERE user_id = 1;
SELECT @time2:= TIMESTAMP(@time);
SELECT @active:=TIMEDIFF(@time2,DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -15 SECOND));
UPDATE active SET active=0 WHERE user_id=1 AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(@active))>=0;
```

which didn't work either.

**THIRD UPDATE**:  I used the suggestion by Adam and I even if it doesn't work as expected, it certainly changes the value 'active' to 0, immediately after I start the event. Ideas?

**SOLUTION**: Thanks to Adam, I used his code with an IF statement:

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
Do
UPDATE active AS t 
SET t.active=IF(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(
t.time_stamp, DATE_ADD(NOW(),
INTERVAL -15 SECOND)))>=0,1,0) 
WHERE user_id=1
```

which it works as intended. I don't why his suggestion didn't work, though.

---

Where did I make a mistake?

Of course, another approach to get this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the value in `active.time_stamp` where `active.user_id = 1`?

Also, I think that your statement might be written more simply.

1. If `time_stamp` in fact contains timestamps then you don't need the call to `TIMESTAMP()`.
2. Remove TIME() function from UPDATE query because [TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2) returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a time value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

So this is how I wrote your statement:

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
DO
UPDATE active t 
SET t.active = 0 
WHERE t.user_id = 1 
AND TIME_TO_SEC(
    TIMEDIFF(
        t.time_stamp, DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -15 SECOND)
    )
)>=0;
```

I've tested that when the value in `active.time_stamp` is greater than now, this event sets the value in `active.active` to 0.

If that still isn't working you might also try something very basic like:

```
CREATE EVENT update_status_test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
DO
UPDATE active t 
SET t.active = 0 
WHERE t.user_id = 1;
```

And if that still isn't working then make sure the event scheduler is actually running.  There are several ways to start it, this is one: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1`

Other notes:
This may not matter now, but as time goes on you will eventually run into the upper-limit of the [TIME type in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The value of active.time_stamp is a regular TIMESTAMP value (e.g. 2011-02-24 00:09:06). I like your simplification of the query, however, it didn't work. Your second snippet worked, though. By the way, I used TIMESTAMP() even if the value already was a TIMESTAMP because when I set a variable (@time, for example), it didn't keep the format; instead, it showed a long digit with some letters. Any further ideas?

Comment: Just in case it could be relevant, I'm using localhost. By the way, I think you meant "UPDATE active **AS** t".

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I posted the working solution as an edit in the question :-)